# How can we get format from the date?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, format, momentjs

We have moment to format a date into give format, like below

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD") // 2022-11-09
```

But how can we get the format from a date, for eg:

```
let inputDate = '02/01/2022';
let outputFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
```

Comment: You can't. At best, you can guess based on other information (such as the current user's locale). See that `'02/01/2022'` can be either `'DD/MM/YYYY'` or `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. Both are used and which one is common depends on where you are in the world.

Comment: You could try to match with a regex, *eg* if `/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}/` matches (don't use this regex it's just an example) then you know it's *either* dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy but it's not yyyy-mm-dd